# start-hbase.sh displays "Error: Could not find or load main class FATAL"

Tags: hbase

I am trying to run hbase in standalone mode.

I have downloaded hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2-bin.tar.gz and extracted it.

I have edited `hbase-env.sh` to include

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/me/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/

export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/home/me/hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2/lib/*
```

I run:

```
$./bin/start-hbase.sh

Error: Could not find or load main class FATAL

Error: Could not find or load main class FATAL
.
.
```

How do I get rid of these errors? There is no exact class listed like in other questions on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue on my 2nd namenode and found that file `\usr\lib\hbase\bin\hbase` had a different version on both servers (maybe the installation steps are different). I copied the work one over to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the java code. Make sure you have maven installed and run the command

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

This is described at http://hbase.apache.org/book/build.html, although the tutorial on how to start hbase doesn't say a word about the compilation step.